# object is disabled {:element=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:

Tags: ruby, watir

We are using a drop-down to select 'Yes' 'No' values from the list. This method is being used across multiple pages. When I run my script it fails saying "Object is disabled" even though it is running fine for first drop down of the page.
Below is the code we are using

```
def select_value(value, field)
    get_screen_element(field).options.map(&:text).include? value }
    Watir::Wait.until{get_screen_element(field).select value}
end
```

Sometimes the script runs fine without errors sometimes it dosen't, its not consistent.

Comment: maybe try this 
"get_screen_element(field).options.map(&:text).enabled?"
then based on output you can move forward

Comment: That solutions was not working.

Comment: the `value` parameter is only either "Yes" or No?" What is an example value of `field`? Is the return value of `get_screen_element` an instance of `Watir::Select`? Can you paste an example of the html of the drop down?

Comment: @Ruby_Learner u can try adding a sleep see if that helps or loop around til the object gets available

Comment: we really need to see the HTML for the control in order to advise you how to interact with it.   If it is not enabled, it could be a custom control that requires you to first click the control for it to transform into something you can pick from..